# How to Change color of a selected Visio shape in c#?

Tags: c#, colors, shapes, visio

I want to programatically change the color of a selected shape in visio. I can identify the shape but can't find out which property to use for changing the color/style of this shape.

I am using shapes from this package:

*Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.IV.Shape.Shapes*

Has anybody experience with changing the color?

Comment: http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=95.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an application where I change the line color by manipulating the cell in the shape sheet, like this:`visioShape.get_Cells("LineColor").Formula = "RGB(255,0,0)";`