# How to get the color of a shape object in MS Visio through C#

Tags: c#, interop, visio, flowchart

I have a shape object drawn as a 'group' such that the two sub-shapes are direct children of the group. All the shapes in the group have distinguishing colors.

I wish to know what is that property which can help me to get the color of the shape objects (Red, Green, White).

I know that shape has style property (Shape.Style) but that does not gives me the color value.

[image]

```
Application visApp = new Application();

Document visDoc = visApp.Documents.Open(VisiofilePath);

var shp = visApp.ActivePage.Shapes.ItemFromID[1];

string shapeColor = string.Empty;

foreach (Visio.Shape s in shp.Shapes)
{
    if(s.Text == "Child Object 1")
     {
        //shapeColor = 
     }

     if(s.Text == "Child Object 2")
     {
        //shapeColor = 
     }        
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the developer tab in Visio?

Comment: @EpicKip : Yes, I have enabled the Developer tab in Visio.

Comment: Ok, if you press show shapesheet you can see the name of the property (just find the one that has the color you are talking about) you can access it by .Cells I think. Here is a question on changing a color, it should work the same for reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44523785/how-to-change-color-of-a-selected-visio-shape-in-c

Comment: @EpicKip : What is that property in ShapeSheet which can help me to know the background color of a shape ?

Comment: You can test it by setting it to a color you know the rgb for and then find that color in the shapesheet. When you find that color you know the property name ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting hold of the fill color is not impacted by whether the shape is part of a group or not.  Once you've got a reference to the right shape then you can look at the respective cells.

Visio has two main methods of setting the fill color - *Pattern fill* and *Gradient fill*.  The latter is from 2013 onwards.

For **Pattern fill**, you're looking at three cells: `FillForegnd`, `FillBkgnd` and `FillPattern`.  Most shapes start off with a solid fill (`FillPattern` 1) and this means that only the `FillForegnd` is used.  For other pattern types you're dealing with both `FillForegnd` and `FillBkgnd`.

For **Gradient fill** the `FillGradientEnabled` cell is set to 1 and this results in the `Fill Gradient Stops` section taking precedents.

In the background, Visio maintains a `Document.Colors` collection.  Some built-in colors can be accessed by index: 0 = black, 1 = white, 2 = red, 3 = green etc all the way up to 23.  Any additional custom colors used are added to the collection and are also given an index.  This means that, given an index, you can look up the color instance in the Colors collection.

Following is some code to demo how to access the various types of coloring.  Given these four shapes:

[image]

The first 3 shapes use Pattern fill, while the last uses Gradient fill.

- Sheet.1 uses an index cell formula (`3`),
- Sheet.2 uses an RGB function,
- Sheet.3 uses a Pattern (`2`) and so uses both Foreground and Background cells
- Sheet.4 uses Gradient stops and so Foreground and Background cells are ignored

... you could use the following code to read the colors at work (note this is using LINQPad as the output window makes it clearer to see what's going on:

```c#
void Main()
{
    var vApp = MyExtensions.GetRunningVisio();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        var shp = vApp.ActivePage.Shapes.ItemFromID[i];
        var colorInfos = new List<ColorInfo>();
        colorInfos.Add(new ColorInfo(shp.CellsU["FillForegnd"]));
        colorInfos.Add(new ColorInfo(shp.CellsU["FillBkgnd"]));
        new
        {
            shp.NameID,
            FillPattern = shp.CellsU["FillPattern"].ResultIU,
            FillGradientEnabled = Convert.ToBoolean(shp.CellsU["FillGradientEnabled"].ResultIU),
            PatternColors = colorInfos,
            GradientColors = FillGradientColors(shp) ?? "Default (10 stops all white)"
        }.Dump();
    }
}

private dynamic FillGradientColors(Visio.Shape shp)
{
    List<string> rgbs = null;
    var iSect = (short)Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionFillGradientStops;
    for (int i = 0; i < shp.RowCount[iSect]; i++)
    {
        var targetCell = shp.CellsSRC[iSect, (short)i, (short)Visio.VisCellIndices.visGradientStopColor];
        if (targetCell.IsInherited == 0)
        {
            if (rgbs is null)
            {
                rgbs = new List<string>();
            }
            rgbs.Add(ColorInfo.RgbString(targetCell));
        }
    }   
    return rgbs;    
}


public class ColorInfo
{
    private Visio.Cell _vCell;

    public ColorInfo(Visio.Cell vCell)
    {
        _vCell = vCell;
        RGB = RgbString(_vCell);
    }

    public string Name => _vCell.Name;
    public string RGB { get; set; }
    public string FormulaU => _vCell.FormulaU;

    public static string RgbString(Visio.Cell cell)
    {
        var colorIdx = cell.Result[(short)Visio.VisUnitCodes.visUnitsColor];
        var c = cell.Document.Colors.Item16[(short)colorIdx];
        return $"RGB({c.Red},{c.Green},{c.Blue})";
    }
}
```

... this produces the following output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nice John, and may I suggest an extra property to get the Hex string too?

```
public static string HexString(Visio.Cell cell)
{
    var colorIdx = cell.Result[(short)Visio.VisUnitCodes.visUnitsColor];
    var c = cell.Document.Colors.Item16[(short)colorIdx];
    return $"#{c.Red.ToString("X2")}{c.Green.ToString("X2")}{c.Blue.ToString("X2")}";
}
```